# Problems installing rgeos and rgdal on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: r, osx-lion, gdal, geos

I'm trying to install the rgeos package (and the rgdal) package. I have a macbook pro running os x 10.7.1 and I have the latest version of R, 2.13.1. I am following the instructions from this site: http://lostingeospace.blogspot.com/2011/08/rgeos-on-macos-x.html

I have installed the latest GDAL complete framework 1.8 from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:frameworks and have downloaded the source file rgeos_0.1-8.tar.gz from CRAN.

In terminal, I input the following, as per the instructions:

```
R64 CMD INSTALL /Users/Pascal/Downloads/rgeos_0.1-8.tar.gz --configure-args='--with-geos-config=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/unix/bin/geos-config'
```

To be thorough, here is the entire output:

```
    * installing to library ‘/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library’
* installing *source* package ‘rgeos’ ...
geos-config: /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/unix/bin/geos-config
GEOS: 3.3.0
CPPFLAGS: -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include
LIBS: -L/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/lib -lgeos
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
*** arch - x86_64
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c gpc_geos.c -o gpc_geos.o
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c init.c -o init.o
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c local_stubs.c -o local_stubs.o
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos.c -o rgeos.o
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_R2geos.c -o rgeos_R2geos.o
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_bbox.c -o rgeos_bbox.o
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_buffer.c -o rgeos_buffer.o
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_coord.c -o rgeos_coord.o
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_geos2R.c -o rgeos_geos2R.o
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_misc.c -o rgeos_misc.o
rgeos_misc.c: In function ‘rgeos_area’:
rgeos_misc.c:5: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘rgeos_miscfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_misc.c: In function ‘rgeos_length’:
rgeos_misc.c:9: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘rgeos_miscfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_misc.c: In function ‘rgeos_distance’:
rgeos_misc.c:51: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_distancefunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_misc.c: In function ‘rgeos_hausdorffdistance’:
rgeos_misc.c:55: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_distancefunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_misc.c: In function ‘rgeos_hausdorffdistancedensify’:
rgeos_misc.c:137: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘rgeos_distancedensifyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_poly2nb.c -o rgeos_poly2nb.o
rgeos_poly2nb.c: In function ‘cb’:
rgeos_poly2nb.c:11: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
rgeos_poly2nb.c: In function ‘rgeos_poly_findInBox’:
rgeos_poly2nb.c:53: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
rgeos_poly2nb.c:62: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘GEOSSTRtree_query_r’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_poly2nb.c: In function ‘rgeos_binary_STRtree_query’:
rgeos_poly2nb.c:127: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
rgeos_poly2nb.c:151: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘GEOSSTRtree_query_r’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_poly2nb.c: In function ‘rgeos_unary_STRtree_query’:
rgeos_poly2nb.c:213: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
rgeos_poly2nb.c:222: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘GEOSSTRtree_query_r’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_poly2nb.c:242: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_predicate_binary.c -o rgeos_predicate_binary.o
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_intersects’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:94: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_contains’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:97: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_disjoint’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:100: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_touches’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:103: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_crosses’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:106: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_within’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:109: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_overlaps’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:112: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_equals’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:115: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_relate’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:118: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_binpredfunc’:
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:149: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:169: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_predicate_unary.c -o rgeos_predicate_unary.o
rgeos_predicate_unary.c: In function ‘rgeos_isvalid’:
rgeos_predicate_unary.c:4: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘rgeos_unarypredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_unary.c: In function ‘rgeos_issimple’:
rgeos_predicate_unary.c:8: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘rgeos_unarypredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_unary.c: In function ‘rgeos_isring’:
rgeos_predicate_unary.c:12: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘rgeos_unarypredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_unary.c: In function ‘rgeos_hasz’:
rgeos_predicate_unary.c:16: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘rgeos_unarypredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_predicate_unary.c: In function ‘rgeos_isempty’:
rgeos_predicate_unary.c:20: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘rgeos_unarypredfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_topology.c -o rgeos_topology.o
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_envelope’:
rgeos_topology.c:5: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_topologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_convexhull’:
rgeos_topology.c:9: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_topologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_boundary’:
rgeos_topology.c:13: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_topologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_getcentroid’:
rgeos_topology.c:17: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_topologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_pointonsurface’:
rgeos_topology.c:21: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_topologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_linemerge’:
rgeos_topology.c:25: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_topologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_unioncascaded’:
rgeos_topology.c:29: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_topologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_unaryunion’:
rgeos_topology.c:36: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘rgeos_topologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_topologyfunc’:
rgeos_topology.c:66: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
rgeos_topology.c: In function ‘rgeos_polygonize’:
rgeos_topology.c:142: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘GEOSPolygonizer_getCutEdges_r’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology.c:143: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘GEOSPolygonize_r’ from incompatible pointer type
    gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_topology_binary.c -o rgeos_topology_binary.o
rgeos_topology_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_difference’:
rgeos_topology_binary.c:4: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘rgeos_binarytopologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_symdifference’:
rgeos_topology_binary.c:7: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘rgeos_binarytopologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_intersection’:
rgeos_topology_binary.c:10: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘rgeos_binarytopologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
rgeos_topology_binary.c: In function ‘rgeos_union’:
rgeos_topology_binary.c:13: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘rgeos_binarytopologyfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_validate.c -o rgeos_validate.o
 gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DHAVEUNARYUNION -I/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/sp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c rgeos_wkt.c -o rgeos_wkt.o
    gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -o rgeos.so gpc_geos.o init.o local_stubs.o rgeos.o rgeos_R2geos.o rgeos_bbox.o rgeos_buffer.o rgeos_coord.o rgeos_geos2R.o rgeos_misc.o rgeos_poly2nb.o rgeos_predicate_binary.o rgeos_predicate_unary.o rgeos_topology.o rgeos_topology_binary.o rgeos_validate.o rgeos_wkt.o -L/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/lib -lgeos -lgeos_c -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgeos.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
    installing to /Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/rgeos/libs/x86_64
    ** R
    ** inst
    ** preparing package for lazy loading
    ** help
    *** installing help indices
    ** building package indices ...
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded
    Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
      unable to load shared object '/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/rgeos/libs/x86_64/rgeos.so':
      dlopen(/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/rgeos/libs/x86_64/rgeos.so, 6): Symbol not found: _GEOSArea_r
      Referenced from: /Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/rgeos/libs/x86_64/rgeos.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/rgeos/libs/x86_64/rgeos.so
    Error: loading failed
    Execution halted
    ERROR: loading failed
    * removing ‘/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/rgeos’
    * restoring previous ‘/Users/Pascal/Library/R/2.13/library/rgeos’
```

The same exact problem arises with the rgdal installation.

I'm not really a programmer....Does anyone have any idea what I should do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know that some geo mac binaries are kept at stats.ox.ac.uk, but I don't have access to a lion machine to test. Try:

```
install.packages(c('rgdal','rgeos'),repos="http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin")
```

If that doesn't work... Do you need to work in 64 bit? try installing with R CMD INSTALL.

Comment: Yes these do work, and I was aware of these. However, those are not the latest versions of the R packages. But thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to get both working in MacOSX Lion by first installing the GDAL frameworks the same as you.

I've installed rgdal from source in the terminal with

```
sudo R64 CMD install rgdal_0.7-1.tar.gz --configure-args='--with-gdal-config=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/unix/bin/gdal-config --with-proj-include=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/include --with-proj-lib=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/lib'
```

Similarly with rgeos:

```
sudo R64 CMD INSTALL rgeos_0.1-8.tar.gz --configure-args='--with-geos-config=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/unix/bin/geos-config'
```

As a note, all of my R packages are installed at the system level, so the `--configure-args='` as given in the instructions work as is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I get the same error. I tried a fresh reinstall of GDAL and ran the commands you suggested. Not sure what's different on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar, if not identical problem when installing rgdal, despite using the proper configure args per Jim M. However, I was able to get rgdal 0.6.33 to work (the version is distributed on KyngChaos at: http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/rgdal-0.6.33-3.zip).

Obviously better to get 0.7-1 to work if you can, but this may be a temporary solution (and sorry I don't know the cause of 0.7-1 failing). I'm also on OS X 10.7.1 running 64-bit R.

Hope that helps.

UPDATE: It looks like the site you're referencing also installed a 0.6 release of rgdal.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, at least I am able to use a recent, if not newest, version of rgdal. I'm just really trying to get the newest version of rgeos because I'm getting an error while running one of the functions, and I'm hoping the update might fix a possible bug.