# Administrative regions map of a country with ggmap and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I can make USA state level unemployment graph with the following code.

```
library(XML)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(maps)

unemp <-
  readHTMLTable('http://www.bls.gov/web/laus/laumstrk.htm',
    colClasses = c('character', 'character', 'numeric'))[[2]]

names(unemp) <- c('rank', 'region', 'rate')
unemp$region <- tolower(unemp$region)

us_state_map <- map_data('state')
map_data <- merge(unemp, us_state_map, by = 'region')

map_data <- arrange(map_data, order)

states <- data.frame(state.center, state.abb)

p1 <- ggplot(data = map_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
p1 <- p1 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cut_number(rate, 5)))
p1 <- p1 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
p1 <- p1 + scale_fill_brewer('Unemployment Rate (Jan 2011)', palette  = 'PuRd')
p1 <- p1 + coord_map()
p1 <- p1 + geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 2)
p1 <- p1 + theme_bw()
p1
```

[image]

Now I want to similar kind of graph for Pakistan. My few attempts results are below:

```
data(world.cities)
Pakistan <- data.frame(map("world", "Pakistan", plot=FALSE)[c("x","y")])

p <- ggplot(Pakistan, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_path(colour = 'green', linestyle = 2) +
     coord_map() + theme_bw()
p <- p + labs(x=" ", y=" ")
p <- p + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank())
p <- p + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(panel.border = element_blank())
print(p)
```

[image]

and

```
library(mapproj)

Country <- "Pakistan"

Get_Map_Country <-
  get_map(
      location = Country
    , zoom = 5
    , scale = "auto"
    , maptype = "roadmap"
    , messaging = FALSE
    , urlonly = FALSE
    , filename = "ggmapTemp"
    , crop = TRUE
    , color = "color"
    , source = "google"
    , api_key
    )

Country1 <-
  ggmap(
      ggmap = Get_Map_Country
    , extent = "panel"
  #  , base_layer
    , maprange = FALSE
    , legend = "right"
    , padding = 0.02
    , darken = c(0, "black")
    )

Country1 <- Country1 + labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude")
print(Country1)
```

[image]

```
Country2 <- Country1 + geom_polygon(data = Pakistan
                    , aes(x=x, y=y)
                    , color = 'white', alpha = .75, size = .2)

print(Country2)
```

[image]

**Questions**

I wonder how to get map of administrative regions of Pakistan as of USA. I know for this we need longitude and latitude of administrative boundaries. I'm wondering how to get longitude and latitude of administrative boundaries for a country. I tried [Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org/country) but without success.

Comment: You had mentioned that you were unable to use the Global Administrative Areas data.  Is it a matter that the data is not what you need, or is it the case that you're having difficulty importing it into R?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I don't know the spatial level of administrative areas you require, but here's two ways
to read in shapefile data and .RData formats from [Global Administrative Areas (gadm.org)](http://www.gadm.org), and converting them into data frames for use in ggplot2. Also, in order to replicate the U.S. map, you will need to plot the administrative area names located at the polygon centroids.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
```

#### Method 1. SpatialPolygonDataFrames stored as .RData format

```
# Data from the Global Administrative Areas
# 1) Read in administrative area level 2 data

load("/Users/jmuirhead/Downloads/PAK_adm2.RData")
pakistan.adm2.spdf <- get("gadm")
```

#### Method2. Shapefile format read in with rgdal::readOGR

```
pakistan.adm2.spdf <- readOGR("/Users/jmuirhead/Downloads/PAK_adm", "PAK_adm2", 
 verbose = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### Creating a data.frame from the spatialPolygonDataframes and merging with a data.frame containing the information on unemployment, for example.

```
pakistan.adm2.df <- fortify(pakistan.adm2.spdf, region = "NAME_2")

# Sample dataframe of unemployment info
unemployment.df <- data.frame(id= unique(pakistan.adm2.df[,'id']),
  unemployment = runif(n = length(unique(pakistan.adm2.df[,'id'])), min = 0, max = 25))

pakistan.adm2.df <- merge(pakistan.adm2.df, unemployment.df, by.y = 'id', all.x = TRUE)
```

#### Extracting names and centoids of administrative areas for plotting

```
# Get centroids of spatialPolygonDataFrame and convert to dataframe
# for use in plotting  area names. 

pakistan.adm2.centroids.df <- data.frame(long = coordinates(pakistan.adm2.spdf)[, 1], 
   lat = coordinates(pakistan.adm2.spdf)[, 2]) 

# Get names and id numbers corresponding to administrative areas
pakistan.adm2.centroids.df[, 'ID_2'] <- pakistan.adm2.spdf@data[,'ID_2']
pakistan.adm2.centroids.df[, 'NAME_2'] <- pakistan.adm2.spdf@data[,'NAME_2']
```

#### Create ggplot with labels for administrative areas

```
p <- ggplot(pakistan.adm2.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill = cut(unemployment,5))) +
geom_text(data = pakistan.adm2.centroids.df, aes(label = NAME_2, x = long, y = lat, group = NAME_2), size = 3) + 
labs(x=" ", y=" ") + 
theme_bw() + scale_fill_brewer('Unemployment Rate (Jan 2011)', palette  = 'PuRd') + 
coord_map() + 
theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank()) + 
theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) + 
theme(panel.border = element_blank())

print(p)
```

[image: Sample output for Pakistan unemployment]

Comment: Thanks @Jim. I am trying to install `rgdal` but get the following message: `  package ‘rgdal’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)`. Any idea how can I get the latest version?

Comment: @Shambho: The message usually means that a binary version is not available for whichever platform you're using.  Instructions on installing rgdal from source are discussed at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168345/problems-installing-rgeos-and-rgdal-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: Tips: 1. you can add a `geom_path` using the same coordinates to add borders; 2. if you see a bunch of spurious straight lines or ugly triangles crossing your map, it's because you forgot to use the `group` aesthetics, and map it to the variable identifying the administrative level you're using. `group` basically tells ggplot to use different paths/polygons for each level of the variable, otherwise it will connect each coordinates in a single line, hence the spurious lines. In your example, I think it should read `group = NAME_2` instead of `group = group` in the `aes` function of `ggplot`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata? That should give you Shapefiles with state/district boundaries for Pakistan.

The [maptools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/index.html) package has functions that let you read and convert Shapefiles to a dataframe that can be used to lay out the boundary polygons.

Comment: Thanks @JConnor for your answer. Would you mind to give more detail how to read Shapefiles in R? Thanks

Comment: I haven't had much experience with maptools so I'd rather point you to this question on [gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19064/how-to-open-a-shapefile-in-r) and also to hadley's github page on using [ggplot with Shapefiles](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles)