# R - Print specific country names in a map using rworldmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, rworldmap

I am creating a heatmap using the map of Europe in rworldmap package in R (since I don't know how to do this with ggmap or ggplot2).

I need to plot the country names of the countries that are present in my dataframe only, not all european countries. How can I do this?
My code:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
#getting colours
colourPalette <- brewer.pal(5,'RdPu')


library(rworldmap)

europe <- data.frame(
  "country" = c("Greece", 
                "France", 
                "Spain",
                "Italy",
                "UK",
                "Finland","Norway","Sweden",
                "Germany",
                "Romania"), 
  "x" = c(2.5, 3, 2.2, 1.8,2.32, 1.99, 2.01, 2.34, 1.88, 2.45))

matched <- joinCountryData2Map(europe, joinCode="NAME", nameJoinColumn="country")





mapParams <- mapCountryData(matched, 
                            nameColumnToPlot="x", 
                            mapTitle="my Titley", 
                            addLegend=FALSE,
                            mapRegion="Europe"
                            ,colourPalette=colourPalette,
                            oceanCol="#404040", missingCountryCol="#A0A0A0")



#adding legend
do.call(addMapLegend
        ,c(mapParams
           ,legendLabels="all"
           ,legendWidth=0.5
           ,legendIntervals="data"
           ,legendMar = 2))

labelCountries()
```

Using `labelCountries()` prints all country names and it's not readable.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little bit help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469444/names-of-the-countries-on-the-plot-with-rworldmap) previously answer:

```
# get the coordinates for each country
country_coord<-data.frame(coordinates(matched),stringsAsFactors=F)

# label the countries
country = c("Greece", 
              "France", 
              "Spain",
              "Italy",
              "UK",
              "Finland","Norway","Sweden",
              "Germany",
              "Romania")

#filter your wanted countrys
country_coord = country_coord[country,]

#insert your labels in plot
text(x=country_coord$X1,y=country_coord$X2,labels=row.names(country_coord))
```

you can add the country labels with `text` but you must extract the coordinates before from your matched coordinates.
Output:

[image: plot]

You might play a bit with `col = "color"` in `text`, since some country can barely been read. Or maybe change the color scale in your map

Comment: Interesting workaround thanks. I guess there is no built in method at the moment. I tried playing with labelCountries but i was missing something in understanding how it works.