# ggmap with value showing on the countries

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggmap

I am looking for some help with the given sample data of countries on one column and count on another column. I am trying a build a geo maps using ggplot showing the count and name of the country in the  respective places of the map when I hover above the country. Below is the sample data given. I tried with the ggmap with the lat and long position to identify the country but not able to show the count and name of the country on hovering.

```
structure(list(Countries = c("USA", "India", "Europe", "LATAM", 
"Singapore", "Phillipines", "Australia", "EMEA", "Malaysia", 
"Hongkong", "Philippines", "Thailand", "New Zealand"
), count = c(143002, 80316, 33513, 3736, 2180, 1905, 1816, 921, 
707, 631, 207, 72, 49)), .Names = c("Countries", "count"), row.names = c(NA, 
13L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the below code.

```
countries = geocode(Countryprofile$Countries)
Countryprofile = cbind(Countryprofile,countries)
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="grey", fill="lightblue")
q<-ggplot(data = Countryprofile) + mapWorld + geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat) ,color="red", size=3)+
  geom_text(data = Countryprofile,aes(x=lon,y=lat,label=Countries))

ggplotly(q)
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code that you've tried & where it's not working for you?

Comment: I have added the code which I worked. I felt the map looks so plain and that's why did not posted initially.

Comment: have you checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578168/how-to-plot-regions-in-a-country-each-shaded-by-some-corresponding-value)?

Comment: Yes, but I could not find on hovering seeing the value and name above the respective place

Comment: how about this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917101/how-do-i-show-the-y-value-on-tooltip-while-hover-in-ggplot2)? I will also recommend that you re-edit your question and let us know what other SO posts have you read in terms of similar questions asked elsewhere. This will add content to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change any attribute in the result from `ggplotly`. In this case you can set the `text` attribute of the 2nd trace (where you markers are defined).

```
plotly_map <- ggplotly(q)
plotly_map$x$data[[2]]$text <- paste(Countryprofile$Countries,
                                     Countryprofile$count, 
                                     sep='<br />')
plotly_map
```

[image]

---

```
library(plotly)
library(ggmap)
Countryprofile  <- structure(list(Countries = c("USA", "India", "Europe", "LATAM", 
                             "Singapore", "Phillipines", "Australia", "EMEA", "Malaysia", 
                             "Hongkong", "Philippines", "Thailand", "New Zealand"
), count = c(143002, 80316, 33513, 3736, 2180, 1905, 1816, 921, 
             707, 631, 207, 72, 49)), .Names = c("Countries", "count"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                      13L), class = "data.frame")
countries = geocode(Countryprofile$Countries)
Countryprofile = cbind(Countryprofile,countries)
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="grey", fill="lightblue")
q<-ggplot(data = Countryprofile) + mapWorld + geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat) ,color="red", size=3)+
  geom_text(data = Countryprofile,aes(x=lon,y=lat,label=Countries))

plotly_map <- ggplotly(q)
plotly_map$x$data[[2]]$text <- paste(Countryprofile$Countries, Countryprofile$count, sep='<br />')
plotly_map
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!